# How to create my own debugger server for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying out selenium using Python, I seen this option in some places

```py
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", debugger_address)
```

How can I create my own debugger server? I've been googling but couldn't find any documentation about this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?